# Trying to create a message feature with socket.io but it doesn't work on Heroku, only on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, websocket, socket.io

In my component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSocket())
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
        socket.emit("joinroom", { ticketId })
    }
}, [socket]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
        socket.on('message', (msg) => {
            const { allMessages } = msg
            dispatch(addMessage(allMessages))
        })
        return () => {
            socket.disconnect()
        }
    }
}, [socket])
```

My back button:

```
  function clicked() {
    socket.emit("leaveroom", { ticketId })
  }
```

The function where I "emit" a message:

```
async function postMessage(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (messageContent !== "") {
        const msg = await dispatch(createOneMessage(ticketId, messageContent));
        socket.emit("message", { ticketId, session, allMessages: msg });
        setMessageContent("");
    } else {
        alert("Please add message");
    }
}
```

This chat feature is only in one component so I figured I bring everything to do with sockets into here and see if I could make it work. The back button is in the navBar that's being rendered separately but it's only there to leave the room. The actual messaging is working correctly (tested with 2 different tabs) but ONLY local host, not when I push to heroku. Thanks so much in advance, I feel that I'm very close to solving this issue.

The way I understand it is: When the user hits this component, it will get a socket from the state (1st use effect). Then after the socket is created, it will join the room using the useParams() ticketId (2nd use effect). Finally it will check for socket.emit('message') and send a message to the server. Just to be clear THIS WORKS ON LOCAL HOST but when I push to heroku there's multiple sockets firing that make the server lag for up to 30 seconds before rendering anything. And 30 seconds afterwards to load another component.

After looking into it more my sockets are also only polling and not actual websockets. My flask backend looks like:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect, generate_csrf
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, join_room, leave_room, emit

from .models import db, User
from .api.user_routes import user_routes
from .api.auth_routes import auth_routes
from .api.tickets import ticket_routes
from .api.departments import department_routes

from .seeds import seed_commands

from .config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)

# Setup login manager
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'auth.unauthorized'


@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))


# Tell flask about our seed commands
app.cli.add_command(seed_commands)

app.config.from_object(Config)
app.register_blueprint(user_routes, url_prefix='/api/users')
app.register_blueprint(auth_routes, url_prefix='/api/auth')
app.register_blueprint(ticket_routes, url_prefix='/api/tickets')
app.register_blueprint(department_routes, url_prefix='/api/departments')
db.init_app(app)
Migrate(app, db)

# Application Security
CORS(app)
socketIo = SocketIO(app=app, cors_allowed_origins='*')


# Since we are deploying with Docker and Flask,
# we won't be using a buildpack when we deploy to Heroku.
# Therefore, we need to make sure that in production any
# request made over http is redirected to https.
# Well.........


@app.before_request
def https_redirect():
    if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'production':
        if request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') == 'http':
            url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
            code = 301
            return redirect(url, code=code)


@app.after_request
def inject_csrf_token(response):
    response.set_cookie(
        'csrf_token',
        generate_csrf(),
        secure=True if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'production' else False,
        samesite='Strict' if os.environ.get(
            'FLASK_ENV') == 'production' else None,
        httponly=True)
    return response


@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def react_root(path):
    if path == 'favicon.ico':
        return app.send_static_file('favicon.ico')
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')


@socketIo.on("message")
def handleMessage(msg):
    if(msg):
        room = f"ticket {msg['ticketId']}"
        msg['allMessages']['owner'] = msg['session']
        socketIo.emit("message", {
                      'allMessages': msg['allMessages'], 'ticketId': msg['ticketId'], 'session': msg['session']}, to=room)


@socketIo.on('joinroom')
def on_join(data):
    if(data):
        print(data, 'dataaaaa')
        room = f"ticket {data['ticketId']}"
        print(room, 'rooooooom')
        join_room(room)


@socketIo.on('leaveroom')
def on_leave(data):
    if(data):
        print(data, 'dataaaaa')
        room = f"ticket {data['ticketId']}"
        print(room, 'rooooooom')
        leave_room(room)


clients = 0


@socketIo.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    global clients
    clients += 1
    print('Scocket connected', clients)

    @socketIo.on('disconnect')
    def disc():
        global clients
        clients -= 1
        print('Socket disconnected', clients)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketIo.run(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the process of sockio connection initialization into a function, and make a fool-proof design for useEffect, remember to unsubscribe from the socket when useEffect returns.

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const Example = () => {
  const [ws, setWs] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ws
      ? initConnectSocket()
      : setWs(io(API_HOST, { path: '/ws', query: { token: auth.userToken } }));
    return () => {
      ws && ws.close();
    };
  }, [ws]);

  const initConnectSocket = () => {
    ws.on('connect', () => {
      ws.on('your channel name', function (msg) {
      });
    });
    ws.on('error', error => {
    });
  };
}

export default Example;
```